# ASP.Net Cascading drop-down with duplicate values in first drop-down field

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have an MS SQL view named [UKTraining_Staff_View] with the following information in it...

```
TUID  | Status | EmployeeID | FirstName | LastName  | ManagedByID | ManagedByWindowsID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2603  | 1      | 1001       | Robert    | Anderson  | 1004        | domain\ADenton
3424  | 1      | 1002       | Chris     | Thompson  | 1004        | domain\ADenton
1845  | 1      | 1003       | Mary      | Wright    | 1004        | domain\ADenton
1257  | 1      | 1004       | Andrew    | Denton    | 1005        | domain\SRogers
2399  | 1      | 1005       | Susan     | Rogers    | 1005        | domain\SRogers
1909  | 1      | 1006       | John      | Stevens   | 1007        | domain\ALee
3216  | 1      | 1007       | Alice     | Lee       | 1005        | domain\SRogers
3155  | 1      | 1008       | John      | Clarke    | 1007        | domain\ALee
```

[TUID] is the unique row entry of the database, [Status] is whether they are employed or not (1 being yes, 0 being no), [EmployeeID] is the unique ID that our HR team give the employee when they start, [FirstName] and [LastName] are self explanatory, [ManagedByID] is the EmployeeID of the Line Manager of this member of staff and [ManagedByWindowsID] is the Windows logon ID of the Line manager of this member of staff.

I have created a cascading drop-down list in my asp.net c# project that allows the Line Manager to select one of the Employees FirstName from the first drop-down box (it will only allow them to select a FirstName value that corresponds to who they manage due to the ManagedByWindowsID = @SubmittedBy section of code), and this then populates the second drop-down box with the Employee LastName value. The code can be seen below...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        cascadingdropdown();
    }
}


protected void cascadingdropdown()
{
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(Mainconn);
    sqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[UKTraining_Staff_View] WHERE ManagedByWindowsID = @SubmittedBy", sqlconn);
    sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubmittedBy", txtSubmittedBy.Text);
    sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    ddlFirstName.DataSource = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
    ddlFirstName.DataTextField = "FirstName";
    ddlFirstName.DataValueField = "TUID";
    ddlFirstName.DataBind();
    ddlFirstName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select First Name--", "0"));
}


protected void ddlFirstName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int TUID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlFirstName.SelectedValue);
    SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(Mainconn);
    sqlconn.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[UKTraining_Staff_View] WHERE TUID =" +TUID, sqlconn);
    sqlcomm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    ddlLastName.DataSource = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
    ddlLastName.DataTextField = "LastName";
    ddlLastName.DataValueField = "EmployeeID";
    ddlLastName.DataBind();
    ddlLastName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Last Name--", "0"));
}
```

The issue with this is that I have duplicate FirstName entries in the database that have unique LastName entries tied to them.

You can see in the database example above that if Alice Lee were to open the application, she would end up with two entries for "John" in the FirstName drop-down, and would have to click on one of them to enable the second drop-down box that would show that persons LastName. This process would show every duplicate FirstName that has a unique LastName. Ideally I would want one Entry for "John" in the FirstName box, and to have two entries in the LastName box ("Stevens" and "Clarke").

Any help or advice on this would be fantastic, as I've now got this far and i'm scratching my head...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause to the SQL query